# REDIS - Get value of multiple keys

Tags: redis

How do I get the value of multiple keys from redis using a sorted set?

```
zadd Users 0 David
zadd Users 5 John
zadd Users 15 Linda
zrevrange Users 0 -1 withscores
```

This will have two users in it.

How can I retrieve the users with key 'David' and 'Linda' in one query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it without introducing a new command in Redis.

For instance, you can fill a temporary set with the names you are interested in, then calculate the intersection between the temporary set and the zset:

```
multi
  sadd tmp David Linda ... and more ...
  zinterstore res 2 tmp Users weights 0 1
  zrange res 0 -1 withscores
  del tmp res
exec
```

With pipelining, this will only generate one roundtrip and you can fill an arbitrary number of input parameters in tmp.

With Redis 2.6, you can also wrap these lines into a server-side Lua script to finally get a command accepting an input list and returning the result you want:

```
eval "redis.call( 'sadd', 'tmp', unpack(KEYS) );
      redis.call( 'zinterstore', 'res', 2, 'tmp', 'Users', 'weights', 0, 1 );
      local res = redis.call( 'zrange', 'res', 0, -1, 'withscores' );
      redis.call( 'del', 'res', 'tmp' ) ; 
      return res
     " 2 David Linda
```

You can safely assume no new command will be added to Redis if it can easily been implemented using scripting.

Comment: How do you enter multi-line lua scripts in the shell? I entered `eval "redis.call( 'sadd', 'tmp', unpack(KEYS) );`, hit ENTER, then got an error (invalid arguments); do I need a special character or something at the end to enter the rest of the script?

Answer (score 32):

You can use Redis MGET

```
redis> MGET key1 key2 nonexisting
1) "Hello"
2) "World"
3) (nil)
```

More here
http://redis.io/commands/mget

Answer (score 1):

One uses a sorted set because you want to deal with items that are sorted. What you are asking for is to not use a sorted set as a sorted set. If you don't care about sort order, then perhaps a sorted set is not what you are looking for. You already can retrieve multiple keys, but not arbitrary ones.

If your primary goal is to retrieve multiple arbitrary keys, use a hash and hmget. If your primary need is to access a sorted set, use sorted set and either go the scripting route or pipeline a series of zscore calls.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this with one command. The closest you can do to get it in one response:

```
MULTI
ZSCORE Users David
ZSCORE Users Linda
EXEC
```

**EDIT**: Alternatively, you can maintain a parallel hash with users' scores, and query it with

```
HMGET UserScores David Linda
```

Comment: so keeping a hash map and a sorted set is a better way you say?

Comment: No, it's not "better". It's just a way to achieve what you want in one query.

Comment: I see. This might be a good improvement to redis I guess. Being able to retrieve the value of multiple keys in one query.